# What is the point in Ruby's String#freeze method if one can still reassign a new value to the frozen variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to understand the use of

`# frozen_string_literal: true`

in RoR and I understand the `freeze` method protects the frozen strings from modification up to some extend, but what's the point given that it's as easy to change the string as just reassigning the value? I would expect freeze to block reassignment too if the idea is protecting the variable from modification.

```
str = "string"
# => "string"
str.freeze
# => "string"
str.frozen?
# => true
str << "fails"
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#         4: from /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
#         3: from /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/irb:23:in `load'
#         2: from /Users/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.6/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
#         1: from (irb):4
# FrozenError (can't modify frozen String: "string")
str = "stringfails... but this is fine?!"
# => "stringfails... but this is fine?!"
str
# => "stringfails... but this is fine?!"
```

I feel like I'm getting confused between freezing the string versus freezing the variable, but a lot of resources mention constants and compare the behaviour to them, so I'm unsure if the idea is to freeze the string assigned to the variable or the variable itself.

Comment: Ruby has no concept of freezing a variable, in part because variables are not objects.

Answer (score 4):

A variable is a pointer. `freeze` does not make the variable "unmutable" (such a thing would be a constant, not a variable), but disallows modifications on the object it points too. The object becomes a bit similar to a number or symbol, which you can't modify either, i.e. which is always kind of frozen:

```
a=:sym1
a=:sym2
```

You can assign something new to `a`, but you can not change `:sym1` itself.

Now to the question what we can use it for, examples on how I use it:

- If I **know** that an object should not be modified after a certain point in the lifetime of the program, I freeze it, and if - during a program error - it is being modified, I get an exception, which is useful for debugging.
- Another example use is with `Hash` and `Set` objects. If you use a `String` as a hash key, or in a Set, Ruby creates a copy of this string, before it is entered in the Hash. This copying is not done if the string is frozen. In our application, we have many hashes, and ran into serious performance problems, because the heap was filled again and again with copies of the strings and garbage collection took a considerable amount of time. There were not so many different strings as such, but they were put into many (often temporary) hashes. As a solution, we implemented a special "Freezer" object, which contains one frozen instance of each string, and use these as Hash keys.

Comment: Thank you - the analogy with symbols is super helpful actually. I like your second use-case example, sounds like a good learning experience, though surely was a costly one. The "Freezer" object seems to be a good solution for you case - I wonder couldn't you just use symbols as keys assuming the copying only applies to String keys in Ruby (and not the values)?

Comment: I considered this, but we need to use (non-modifying) String methods often on those objects, and using symbols would mean that we have to convert them back to strings every time, which would make the overall performance behaviour even worse.

Answer (score 2):

The general idea behind freezing objects is to make them immutable. This is a valuable trait to have in some situations. Say, you're making an API client, for example.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
username = "sergio"
password = "password"
host = "https://example.com/api"
client = MyAPI::Client.new(host, username, password)
```

Here, once `client` obtained a reference to a frozen string, it can be sure that this string will never change (from the point of view of this client). So other code can't make `host` to point to another site or change the password to `"bogus"` and so on, and have `client` observe these changes.

With regular, unfrozen strings, you can mutate them in-place in a bunch of ways: `gsub!`, `replace`, etc. This affects all references.

This problem is much more pronounced with hashes and arrays, IMHO. In my experience, you mutate them in-place much more often. Like this, for example:

```rb
h[:foo] = :bar
ary[0] = 3.14
```

So if you want to make sure this hash or array never changes*, `freeze` it.

* caveat: freezing a hash or array only protects its immediate structure. Values in a hash and elements in an array are still mutable, you have to freeze them individually.

Comment: Oh, yes! API calls would definitely be a good use-case for that - I can see how now. I appreciate your note on freezing hashed vs freezing the individual elements in them - this can easily get confusing and I think it's somehow linked to the behaviour of frozen elements in interpolation as described [here](https://scriptday.com/blog/2020/09/16/ruby-3-0-interpolated-strings-are-no-longer-frozen). Or rather, this is the reverse - freezing the individuals, doesn't mean the bigger structure is frozen. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the variable like a sign that says: "oh you are looking for the string? it is over there" and it points to the string itself. So you have a "sign" (the variable) and the object itself (the string)

When you `freeze`, you freeze the object, not the sign that points to the object. So you can not change the frozen string, but you can still make that sign point to something else.

I have called *name* a variable that points to my object (a String holding my name)

```
name = "Pascal"
```

I can make the variable point to another object (your name)

```
name = "noname"
```

The String "Pascal" might still be somewhere in memory but I don't know where. It is lost and will get arbage collected at some point to free the memory.

I don't want anybody to change the value of the string, so i freeze it

```
name.freeze
```

But i still can point that variable into another direction

```
name = "Hondo"
```

Now there is a frozen String somewhere in memory containg "noname" but again, it is lost since we don't have any sign pointing to it. This frozen string will, if your program runs long enough), be garbage collected as well.

We can also have multiple variables pointing to the same object:

```
variable_a = "something"
=> "something"
variable_b = variable_a
=> "something"
variable_a.object_id
=> 70104549867280
variable_b.object_id
=> 70104549867280
```

`object_id` gives you an identifier of the object the variable is pointing to. It isthe same for `vairable_a` and `variable_b` so they are pointing to the same object.

Comment: Ah, so it's freezing the string itself. And in case a new value has been assigned, it's just pointing to the new one The old one still stays frozen and probably existing somewhere in memory.
Thank you - that makes more sense now.

Comment: Updated the answer, does that help?

Comment: Re "The old one still stays frozen and probably existing somewhere in memory" that's true but if it's not referenced by any variable anywhere, then it'll be removed by garbage collection.

Comment: Yes, it most likely is collected by the garbage collector sooner or later (i mentioned that a bit above but will add it there as well).

Comment: Yes, just tried your examples as well and that's great - clarifies it fully now. Thanks, Pascal!